# Suming a nested array's indices together with JavaScript map

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working to get a better grasp of nested arrays.  I have an array with two arrays nested inside as the indices.  I am trying to figure out how to add these.  I understand how you would add them if they were separate arrays, but I am wondering how/if possible  you can map through a nested array to add the indices.

The current array that I am looking at is

```
strArr= [[5, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3] ];
```

If this was two separate arrays I could simply run a map with index as a second parameter  such as ...

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [1,1,1,2,9];
arr.map((a, i) => a + arr2[i]);
```

However, I am not able to achieve this with the index

```
strArr.map((a,idx) => a[0][idx] + a[1][idx]) // [Nan, Nan]
```

The best I can do to get any addition is

```
    return strArr.map(a => a[0] + a[1]) // [7,4]
```

However,  I am not sure why I am only getting **[7,4]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over the outer array, which has a length of `2`. Therefore you get a result of two elements.

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for the outer array and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for the inner arrays and sum the values at a given index.

```js
var strArr= [[5, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3] ];

console.log(strArr.reduce((r, a) => (a.forEach((b, i) => r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b), r), []));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to sum your indices

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [1, 1, 1, 2];

var result = arr 
    .map((item, i) => i + arr2[i])
    .reduce((memo, value) => memo + value);
console.debug("res: ", result);
// res:  11
```

However you will have to handle cases when the array lengths are not equal to eachover or not numerical values

Answer (score 0):

1. Map each element in the parent array (sub-arrays)
2. For each sub-array reduce and sum

```js
strArr= [[5, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3] ];
var result = strArr.map((arr)=>arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just target/split the original array?

> "If this was two separate arrays I could simply run a map with index as a second parameter"

Then make it two separate arrays...

```js
strArr= [[5, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3] ]; /* becomes strArr[0] & strArr[1] */

console.log(strArr[0].map((a, i) => a + strArr[1][i]));
```

Comment: I was able to do this.  It was more of a challenge to figuring a different way to loop through this.